# Python pandas: Double columns

Tags: python, pandas

Currently getting to know pandas. I was wondering what the syntax df[df["column"]["column"]] is about, especially what is the difference to df[df[column, column]]?

Example:
`df[df['price']<300]['price'])`

Thanks for your advice :)

Comment: In my opinion a lot of pandas complexity comes from stringing together multiple commands at once. Try `df[df['price']<300]` by itself and then take a look at the output. then try adding the `['price']` and what comes out

Comment: Thanks for your tip. Thats it! Without the extra column, the whole dataframe (all columns) wil be output including every row with a price lower than 300. The second "price" tag specifies so that only this column will be output.

Comment: it would be great if you could write an answer to your own question with an short example  so someone else with the same question in the future might find this!